# Matching an unescaped balanced pair of delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I match a balanced pair of delimiters not escaped by backslash (that is itself not escaped by a backslash) (without the need to consider nesting)? For example with backticks, I tried this, but the escaped backtick is not working as escaped.

```
regex = /(?!<\\)`(.*?)(?!<\\)`/
"hello `how\` are` you"
# => $1: "how\\"
# expected "how\\` are"
```

And the regex above does not consider a backslash that is escaped by a backslash and is in front of a backtick, but I would like to.

How does StackOverflow do this?

The purpose of this is not much complicated. I have documentation texts, which include the backtick notation for inline code just like StackOverflow, and I want to display that in an HTML file with the inline code decorated with some span material. There would be no nesting, but escaped backticks or escaped backslashes may appear anywhere.

Comment: Don't use regex...it isn't meant for matching this kind of text. Use a real parser instead.

Comment: @nneonneo Aren't parsers written using regex?

Comment: Nononono, parsers are not written using regex. At best, the lexer (which produces tokens) might be written in terms of regular expressions. Parsers take a stream of tokens and turn them into some structured format. They are a lot more general, and powerful, than regular expressions.

Comment: @nneonneo Nononono, parsers won't work without a lexar. If lexar is written with regex, parsers are using regular expressions.

Comment: But parsers can work without a lexer -- they just have to parse simpler strings (e.g. languages with one-character variable names). I think, though, if you're arguing whether parsers use regex or not, then you are missing the point...

Comment: @nneonneo Usually, when people claim not to use regex for parsing, the point is to not reinvent the wheel. The point is not that it cannot be done with regexes but that it has already been done. Since my purpose is not complicated enough to use a parser, and furthermore accompanying a parser as a part of the program just for this is too much, it misses the point to mention to use a parser here.

Comment: @sawa IMHO when people say not to use regex for parsing they mean you should not do the whole parsing using regex, since most things people want to parse are not expressible by [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) (such as balanced parenthesis with nesting, arbitrary-length lists of comma separated tokens, etc). In other words, people start with simple cases (like yours) and try to do more and more complicated things, not noticing regex became the wrong tool for the job. The "enhanced capabilities" of most regex engines unfortunatly encourages this behavior...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lookbehind is the first thing everyone thinks of for this kind of problem, but it's the wrong tool, even in flavors like .NET that support unrestricted lookbehinds.  You can hack something up, but it's going to be ugly, even in .NET.  Here's a better way:

```
`[^`\\]*(\\.[^`\\]*)*`
```

The first part starts from the opening delimiter and gobbles up anything that's not the delimiter or a backslash.  If the next character is a backslash, it consumes that and the character following it, whatever it may be.  It could be the delimiter character, another backslash, or anything else, it doesn't matter.

It repeats those steps as many times as necessary, and when neither `` [^`\\] `` nor `\\.` can match, the next character must be the closing delimiter.  Or the end of the string, but I'm assuming the input is well formed.  But if it's *not* well formed, this regex will fail very quickly.  I mention that because of this other approach I see a lot:

```
`(?:[^`\\]+|\\.)*`
```

This works fine on well-formed input, but what happens if you remove the last backtick from your sample input?

```
"hello `how\` are you"
```

According to RegexBuddy, after encountering the first backtick, this regex performed 9,252 distinct operations (or steps) before it could give up and report failure; mine failed in ten steps.

**EDIT** To extract just the par inside the delimiters, wrap that part in a capturing group.  You'll still have to remove the backslashes manually.

```
`([^`\\]*(?:\\.[^`\\]*)*)`
```

I also changed the other group to non-capturing, which I should have done from the start.  I don't avoid capturing religiously, but if you *are* using them to capture stuff, any other groups you use should be non-capturing.

**EDIT** I think I've been reading too much into the question.  On StackOverflow, if you want to include literal backticks in an inline-code segment or a comment, you use three backticks as the the delimiter, not just one.  Since there's no need to escape backticks,  you can ignore backslashes as well.  Your regex could turn out to be as simple as this:

````
```(.*?)```
````

Dealing with the possibility of false delimiters, you use the same basic technique:

````
```([^`]*(?:`(?!``)[^`]*)*)```
````

Is this what you're after?

---

By the way, this answer doesn't contradict @nneonneo's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060967/matching-an-unescaped-balanced-pair-of-delimiters#comment17739643_13060967) above.  This answer doesn't consider the context in which the match is taking place.  Is it in the source code of a program or web page?  If it is, did the match occur inside a comment or a string literal?  How do I even know the first backtick I found wasn't escaped?  Regexes don't know anything about the context in which they operate; that's what parsers are for.

Comment: I haven't fully read your answer yet. But as I wrote above, I don't need to consider nesting (nor a situation where the whole expression is inside/after a backtick opening). Yours look promising. I just need time to fully examine it.

Comment: I think this is very close to what I want, but still incorrectly captures when the first backtick in the string is escaped. Should I use a negative lookbehind just for the initial part, or not?

Comment: +1 for the performance considerations, that never occured to me before (how many backtracks the engine would perform on a malformed input when using the "or" variant)

Comment: @sawa, that's what I was talking about at the end.  In a programming language that supports string literals delimited by quotation marks, a `\"` sequence *outside* of a string literal makes no sense, and is (AFAIK) always treated as a syntax error.  If that's not true in you're case, you probably won't be able to solve your problem with a single regex.

Comment: @AlanMoore Everything I mention here is within a string literal. Anything can appear within a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need nesting, regexes can indeed be a proper tool. Lexers of programming languages, for instance, use regexes to tokenize strings, and strings usually allow their own delimiters as an escaped content. Anything more complicated than that will probably need a full-blown parser though.

The "general formula" is to match an escaped character (`\\.`) or any character that's valid as content but don't need to be escaped (`[^{list of invalid chars}]`). A "naïve" solution would be joining them with **or** (`|`), but for a more efficient variant see [@AlanMoore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062604/520779).

The complete example is shown below, in two variants: the first assumes than backslashes should **only** be used for escaping **inside** the string, the second assumes that a backslash **anywhere in the text** escapes the next character.

```
`((?:\\.|[^`\\])*)`

(?:\\.|[^`\\])*`((?:\\.|[^`\\])*)`
```

Working examples [here](http://rubular.com/r/yuyo9TVtfS) and [here](http://rubular.com/r/nmaoaKki09). However, as @nneonneo commented (and I endorsed), regexes are not meant to do a complete parse, so you'd better keep things simple if you want them to work out right (do you want to **find** a token in the text, or do you want to **delimit** it already knowing where it starts? The answer to that question is important to decide which strategy works best for your case).

Comment: This regex, given `"hello \\`how` are` you"`, incorrectly matches `how` instead of the expected ` are`.

Comment: @nneonneo My answer only considered escaping the backtick, ignoring everything else **including** the backslash itself. But the general case (`\\.`) would escape anything (like some lexers do, even if the escaped character is considered invalid by the semantic analysis). I'll update my answer with a more robust example.

Comment: @sawa backslashes **outside** the string are not supposed to be escaped, are they?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Backslashes can appear anywhere in the string, escaped or not. But I don't know what you mean by "outside the string"; everything mentioned is inside the string.

Comment: @sawa as Alan Moore said, context is everything. If you want to interpret **both** a string (quote delimited text) and some syntax **inside** that string (backtick delimited text), **at the same time**, you're probably doing too much...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Now I think I understand that you are using the word "string" to mean "substring that is captured". If that is the case, I do not need to think of that. As I wrote, there is no nesting. However, the first backtick in the string (not substring) may be escaped.

Comment: @sawa if what you mean is "in the context, an escaped backtick should not start a match", then my last regex should work fine for you.

Comment: @mgibsonbr I checked your last link. It matches from the beginning of the string to almost the end of it.

Comment: @sawa but the capturing group gets the correct contents, doesn't it? If you want to match **only** the backticked part, I believe you'd really have to use lookbehind (and since I have no experience with it, I can't be of any help). At least if you want to avoid an escaped start, there's no way of doing it without including it in the match (hence the need for lookbehind).