# How to do regex balance matching, when the brackets are possibly 'escaped'

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Say I have a toy language that has the following string:

```
fun( fun3\(\) ) + fun4()
```

Here, 'fun' receives 'fun3()' as its argument.  And fun4() is left for later evaluation.

Now say I have a different string:

```
fun( fun3()\\) )
```

Here, 'fun' should receive 'fun3()\' and we have a ) leftover.

Escaping a '\' by doing '\' means we get it literally - and thusly, /that pair/ of '\'s no longer escapes the bracket. A third \ would again escape the bracket, etc.

Now, say I want to match this string using C#)'s more capable Regex library, using the way it matches brackets, and **specifically** in that way; I am aware that normally I'd use a proper parsing method rather than (expanded) regular expressions. This is less about what tool I should be using, and more about what this tool can do.

I'll use the following three strings as my tests.

```
fun(abc) fun3()
```

Which will mean fun() receives 'abc' as its argument. fun3() is leftover.

```
fun(\\\)\)) fun3()
```

Which will mean fun() receives '\))' as its argument. fun3() is leftover.

```
fun(fun2(\)\\\() ) fun3()
```

Which will mean fun() receives 'fun2()\()' as its argument. fun3() is leftover.

As Alan Moore presumed in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060967/matching-an-unescaped-balanced-pair-of-delimiters), the first thing I want to use is LookBehind.
The Regex below handles the first case, but obviously not the second case. It's too quick to take the first ')' it sees.

```
Regex catchRegex = new Regex(@"^fun\((.*?(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)(?<ClosingChar>[\)])(.*$)");
string testcase0 = @"fun(abc) fun3()";
string testcase1 = @"fun(\\\)\)) fun3()";
string testcase2 = @"fun(fun2(\)\\\() ) fun3()";
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[1]); // 'abc'
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[2]); // ' fun3()'
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[3]); // ')'

Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[1]); // '\\\)\)'
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[2]); // ' fun3()'
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[3]); // ')'

Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[1]); // 'fun2(\)\\\(' <--!
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[2]); // ' ) fun3()' <--!
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[3]); // ')'
```

So now we're down to doing what .NET can do. Bracket matching. It passes on the first test... but because I don't tell it not to care about things that are escaped, it fails the others. This is only fair.

```
Regex bracketRegex = new Regex(@"^fun\(([^\)]*|(?<BR>)\(|(?<-BR>)\))(?<ClosingChar>[\)])(.*$)");
Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[1]); // 'abc'
Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[2]); // ' fun3()'
Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[3]); // ''

Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[1]); // '\\\'
Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[2]); // '\)) fun3()'
Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[3]); // ''

Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[1]); // 'fun2(\' <--!
Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[2]); // '\\\() ) fun3()' <--!
Console.WriteLine(bracketRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[3]); // ''
```

But the problem is the next step. Combining version 1 and version 2 doesn't actually get me anything or anywhere. So to you the question, StackOverflow, is there a way to do this?

```
Regex bracketAwareRegex = new Regex(@"^fun\(([^\)]*|(?<BR>)(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\(|(?<-BR>)(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\))(?<ClosingChar>[\)])(.*$)");
Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[1]); // 'abc'
Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[2]); // ' fun3()'
Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[3]); // ''

Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[1]); // '\\\'
Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[2]); // '\)) fun3()'
Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[3]); // ''

Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[1]); // 'fun2(\' <--!
Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[2]); // '\\\() ) fun3()' <--!
Console.WriteLine(bracketAwareRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[3]); // ''
```

Because that didn't work.

Comment: @leppie To me, it sounds more like you didn't read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose this regex:

```
@"^fun\(((?:[^()\\]|\\.|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))+(?(o)(?!)))\)(.*$)"
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/2uibII)

I removed the `ClosingChar` capture.

Results:

```
string testcase0 = @"fun(abc) fun3()";
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[1]); // 'abc'
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase0).Groups[2]); // ' fun3()'

string testcase1 = @"fun(\\\)\)) fun3()";
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[1]); // '\\\)\)'
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase1).Groups[2]); // ' fun3()'

string testcase2 = @"fun(fun2(\)\\\() ) fun3()";
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[1]); // 'fun2(\)\\\()'
Console.WriteLine(catchRegex.Match(testcase2).Groups[2]); // ' fun3()'
```

---

I have another way of dealing with escaped characters, which is using something a bit like:

```
(?:[^()\\]|\\.)
```

Which ends in the one above when combine with the balancing groups.

```
^fun\(            Match 'fun(' literally at the beginning
(                
  (?:            
    [^()\\]       Match anything not '(', ')' or '\'
  |              
    \\.           Match any escaped char
  |              
    (?<o>\()    Match a '(' and name it 'o'
  |            
    (?<-o>\))   Match a ')' and remove the named 'o' capture
  )+           
  (?(o)(?!))    Make regex fail if 'o' doesn't exist
)                
\)(.*$)           Match anything leftover
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Jerry. I can't believe I didn't 'see' that approach on escaped characters.